# primes and semiprimes found with $n=11,13,17,19 \mod 30$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, semiprimes

For $n=11,13,17,19 \mod 30$ what percentage of all primes and all semiprimes less than $100, 1000, 10000...$ will be produced by $n$?

Up to $20,000$ I found $50\%$ were primes and more than $50\%$ were semiprimes. If one continued the number of trials, would the results be closer to primes $10\%$ and semiprimes $20\%$?

Comment: Up to 20,000 I found 50% were primes and more than 50% were semiprimes.  If one continued the number of trials, would the results be closer to primes 10% and semiprimes  20%?

Comment: Your comment doesn't match my reading of the question. The question asks "what percentage of all primes will be created", and I read that as "What percentage of primes $\leqslant x$ have a remainder of $11,13,17$, or $19$ modulo $30$" (and similarly for the semiprimes). Your comment answers the question "what percentage of numbers ($\leqslant x$) $\equiv 11,13,17,19 \pmod{30}$ is prime/semiprime". Which is the question that you really want answered?

Comment: The question asks "of  ALL primes and ALL semiprimes less than these powers of ten, what percentage of these will be created by n?"  Find the number of each, then find the percentage of these that are produced by n.  Is it possible to answer this for the semiprimes?  The 10% and 20% were just approximations NOT limits.

Comment: I can figure what you guys are doing.  The question has been answered and now you want me to edit what has already been answered.  This makes NO sense.  Secondly, is the question about semprimes too difficult to answer?  Find ALL the odd semiprimes less than each power of ten and  count how many are produced by n to get the percentage found.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible readings of your question (ignoring the semiprimes bit):

- what proportion of the primes up to $n$ are congruent to 11, 13, 17, or 19 mod 30?
- what proportion of the positive integers up to $n$ congruent to 11, 13, 17, or 19 mod 30 are primes?

The [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions) answers both of these.  The total number of primes up to $n$ is approximately $Li(n)$, where $Li(n)$ is the so-called logarithmic integral,
$$Li(n) = \int_2^n {dt \over \log t}.$$

The total number of primes up to $n$ congruent to $a$ mod 30, where $a$ is relatively prime to 30, is approximately

$$ {1 \over \phi(30)} Li(n) $$

where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function -- that is, $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.  In particular $\phi(30) = 8$, the size of the set $\{ 1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 \}$.

So one-eighth of all primes up to $n$ are congruent to 11 mod 30, and similarly for 13, 17, or 19.  One-half of all primes up to $n$ are congruent mod 30 to one of these four.

On the other hand, there are approximately $4n/30$ integers less than $n$ which are congruent to 11, 13, 17, or 19 mod 30.  Of these approximately $Li(n)/2$ are prime, so the proportion of such integers which are prime is approximately

$$ {Li(n)/2 \over 4n/30} = {15 \over 4} {Li(n) \over n}$$

in particular $Li(n)$ is approximately $n/(\log n)$ and so this is approximately

$$ {15 \over 4 \log n}. $$

As $n \to \infty$ this gets as small as you like.  In particular it does not approach a positive constant like your conjectured $10\%$. The proportion of positive integers less than $n$ which are prime is about $1/(\log n)$, so your set is "richer" in primes than the positive integers by a factor of $15/4$.